# Attribute groups, linking, and email sending clarification

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, data-designer

**Context:** 
I have 2 data extensions that need to be merged in order to send an email. The 2nd data extension includes Member ID and a unique generated URL based on Member ID. What I would normally do is do an import, create a query, and perform a matchback to get the results (no issues there)...

**Question:**
However, in lieu of that, can I create an attribute group linking both data extensions so that it sends the email and includes the unique URL to the subscriber at send time rather than the manual query effort?

I'm trying to find other uses besides using data designer for journeys. Not sure if my ask is feasible or not.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - just needed to create a data relationship between the 2 tables in Email Studio, and then use AMPscript to populate the URL.

I guess Contact Builder and attribute groups are mainly used for Journeys.

```
%%[ 
VAR @UniqueID, @lookupvalue
SET @lookupvalue = SubscriberKey 
SET @UniqueID = Lookup("ImportURLUnique","UniqueID","SubscriberKey",@lookupvalue)
]%%
```